# Calendar Provider batch insert

Tags: android, android-calendar

Hi I'm trying to insert a couple of calendar events with [Calendar Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) via an batch insert. My code fails with a IllegalArgumentException

```
 private void synchronizeCalendar(long calID){
    TLApplication.getDB().getDB().beginTransaction();
    try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        TLCalendar calendar = TLApplication.getDB().loadCalendar();
        if(calendar.days!=null && calendar.days.size()> 0){
            for (TLDay day : calendar.days) {
                for (TLEvent event : day.events) {
                    List<TLComponent> comps = TLApplication.getDB().loadComponents(event.cid);
                    if(comps.size()>0){
                        TLComponent comp = comps.get(0);
                        //new batch operation
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(getCalendarUri())
                                .withValue(Events.DTSTART, getStartDate(event, comp)) //long
                                .withValue(Events.DTEND, getEndDate(event, comp)) //long
                                .withValue(Events.TITLE, getTitle(event)) //String
                                .withValue(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, getLocation(event)) //String
                                .withValue(Events.DESCRIPTION, getNotes(comp)) //String
                                .withValue(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID) //long
                                .withValue(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID()) //String
                                .build());
                    }
                }
            }
            if(ops.size() > 0){
                ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
                ContentProviderResult[] results = cr.applyBatch(CalendarContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "addBatchEvent: " + result.uri.toString());
                }
            }else{
                Log.w(TAG, "No batch operations found! Do nothing");
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "synchronizeCalendar", e);

    } finally{
        TLApplication.getDB().getDB().endTransaction();
    }
}
```

The Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'calendar_id' is invalid

The pattern for this code is the "ContactManager" sample from sdk: *docs/resources/samples/ContactManager/src/com/example/android/contactmanager/ContactAdder.html*

Has anybody experience with batch insert to calendar? Do I need to implement a [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#sync-adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the bug in my implementation. I've used `getCalendarUri()` to get the `Calendars.CONTENT_URI`, but I must use `Events.CONTENT_URI` for the events.

Comment: I had the same thing. Finding that was not easy, so thank you for your post :)